# Class instance member that depends on class member attribute

Tags: c++, class, c++11

My faculty provided me with a class that represents a Binary Tree and we have to use it for an assigment.
So I'm doing a class called cluster and the thing goes like this:

**BinTree** (I've only copied what I though it's the minimum necessary):

```
template <typename T>
class BinTree {
public:

// Constructs an empty tree. Θ(1).
BinTree ()
:   p(nullptr)
{   }

// Constructs a tree with a value x and no subtrees. Θ(1).
explicit BinTree (const T& x);

// Constructs a tree with a value x and two subtrees left and right. Θ(1).
explicit BinTree (const T& x, const BinTree& left, const BinTree& right);
```

**Cluster:**

```
class Cluster {
    private:

    BinTree<std::pair<std::string, double>> _cluster;

    public:
    Cluster();
    //etc....
}
```

Since I can't use inheritance (We haven't reached that part yet) I really don't have any idea how the constructors of Cluster would be. A cluster object would be a Binary tree but I start with the "leaves"(English isn't my first language so I don't know how to call it), therefore I have to create a Cluster with a string an a double = 0.0.

I've assumed the Cluster constructor would be like this:

```
Cluster(const std::string& id) : _cluster(make_pair(id, 0.0)){};
```

Is this correct?

Then, having 2 specific Clusters I will merge them into a one. This new Cluster, because its _cluster attribute is a binary tree, would be the parent of the previous ones, here is were I would have to use the 3rd constructor of BinTree but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood, you want to merge 2 clusters so, you can do it similary to how it is done in the BinTree class.

```
explicit Cluster ( Cluster& left, const Cluster& right){
    _cluster = Cluster(left, right) ;
}
```

I don't undeestand the functionality of the cluster class, it might be easier to use BinTree directly.